# SQl Loop through a column text field to find ids and join those ids with another table

Tags: sql, textblob

A column contains a large text and belongs to table A.

Column Content: **blablabla 123 id:ID1 id:ID2 id:ID3 id:ID4 xyz**

The contents of the column field are not known but I have a function which getsID and returns ID1 only.
There is another table B which has a column id.
Could you please assist to extract all ids from text file and join them with Table B?
Thanks in advance.

Expectation would be to be able to perform a join with those ids.

| A.id | B.Letter |
| --- | --- |
| ID1 | k |
| ID2 | l |

Comment: Please leave some sql-Code here. It seems, as you are looking for an ordinary join-operator.

Comment: Also update your question with the DDL for the 2 tables in question